# ASIFormDataRequest is undeclared

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

i am new in iphone programing and faced a query with ASIFormDataRequest

i just define ASIFormDataRequest with url

```
 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

but it give  me a error like ASIFormDataRequest undeclared
so tell me is any header file need to import i also add some frame work but i don't know which headerfile imported or it required to create a class for ASIFormDataRequest and by using object of that class i redefine what can i do to remove this error

Answer (score 0):

Did u add the `ASIHTTPRequest` files to your project and imported the files in classes where you need them. Pls go through this for [reference](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions)

Comment: thanks 4 replay no i am not ad ASIHTTPRequest pl tell me how and where it add

Answer (score 0):

Hii Yogesh :

Just synthesize - ASIFormDataRequest *requestASI;

```
[self setRequestASI:[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:emailURL]];


[requestASI setDelegate:self];
```

then you can use this Wrapper Class - its a great One!

Comment: ya i try to synthesize ASIFormDataRequest *requestASI; i also add this in .h file but it give me a error like expected specific qualifier when it define in .h file and after synthesize it give error like specifier * can i add class file ASIHTTPRequest.h and .m and then i import it if yes then what code i wrote here